# Extracting data from a .txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this data in my sample.txt file:

```
A2B3,32:45:63
A4N6,17:72:35
S2R3,13:14:99
```

What I want to do is to put those data in an array but I'm having problems separating those with commas.

My code goes like this:

```
with open('sample.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        x = f.read().splitlines()
        print(x)
```

And the output goes like this:

```
['A2B3,32:45:63','A4N6,17:72:35','S2R3,13:14:99']
```

I altered my code in different ways to separate those two variables with commas but I can't seem to make it work. Can someone help me achieve this output?

```
['A2B3','32:45:63','A4N6','17:72:35','S2R3','13:14:99']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `line.split(',')` to seperate the line at the ",".

```py
x = []
with open('sample.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for j in line.split(','):
            x.append(j.split('\n')[0])
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably could just do:

```
data = list()
with open('sample.txt', 'r') as f:
for line in f.readlines():
    data.append(line)
```

And you should end up with list of appended lines. It's also faster on big files than just .splitlines() since .readlines() is implemented in C and doesn't load whole file in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, which splits the lines into a list like you have, and then splits those items at the comma.

```
filename = "sample.txt"

with open(filename) as file:
    lines = file.read().split("\n")

output = []
for l in lines:
    for j in l.split(","):
        output.append(j)

print(output)
```

Output:

```
['A2B3', '32:45:63', 'A4N6', '17:72:35', 'S2R3', '13:14:99']
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, it's very simple...

after separate all line, you get list look like

```
['A2B3,32:45:63','A4N6,17:72:35','S2R3,13:14:99']
```

then after again you separate that each element by comma(,) and add it into new list like

```
list_a = ['A2B3,32:45:63','A4N6,17:72:35','S2R3,13:14:99']
final_list = []

for i in list_a:
    part_1, part_2 = i.split(',')
    final_list.append(part_1)
    final_list.append(part_2)

print(final_list)
```

And it will give your desire output like

```
['A2B3','32:45:63','A4N6','17:72:35','S2R3','13:14:99']
```

it is not a redundant way but for you very easy to understand

Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, just iterating once over the lines:

```
res = []
with open('sample.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        res += line.strip().split(",")
print(res)
```

Gives:

```
['A2B3', '32:45:63', 'A4N6', '17:72:35', 'S2R3', '13:14:99']
```

Though I wonder why you'd want to have everything in a list, I think you are missing the link between the items, maybe could be more useful to keep them in tuples like this:

```
res = []
with open('sample.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        res.append(tuple(line.strip().split(",")))
print(res)
```

Gives:

```
[('A2B3', '32:45:63'), ('A4N6', '17:72:35'), ('S2R3', '13:14:99')]
```

Answer (score 0):

FMPOV this result is better to go along. But nevermind, I guess, you'll find your solution from one of those poseted here.

```
x = [i.replace("\n","").split(',')for i in open('data.txt', 'r')]
print(x)
print(x[0][1])
```